# UIImage from RGBA having Alpha becoming white

Tags: objective-c, alpha, rgba

I am making a military strategy game. When an army in my game takes over a territory, I want to be able to change the color of the territory on the map so that it shows the new controller of that territory. Here is the code I have that changes a territory's image:

I would write this line for example:

```
UIImage *newImg = [self imageOfTerritoryWithNewArmy:@"japan" AndOldTerritoryImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ireland.gif"]];
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
-(UIImage *)createImageWithRGB:(NSArray *)colorData width:(NSInteger)width height:(NSInteger)height{
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(width*height*4);
    for (int i=0; i<width*height; ++i)
    {
        CGFloat red;
        CGFloat green;
        CGFloat blue;
        CGFloat alpha;
        UIColor *color = colorData[i];
        if ([color respondsToSelector:@selector(getRed:green:blue:alpha:)]) {
            [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
        } else {
            const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
            red = components[0];
            green = components[1];
            blue = components[2];
            alpha = components[3];
        }
        if(alpha > 0){
            rawData[4*i] = red * 255;
            rawData[4*i+1] = green * 255;
            rawData[4*i+2] = blue * 255;
            rawData[4*i+3] = alpha * 255;
        }
        else{
            rawData[4*i] = 255;
            rawData[4*i+1] = 255;
            rawData[4*i+2] = 255;
            rawData[4*i+3] = 0;
        }
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                          rawData,
                                                          width*height*4,
                                                          NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                    height,
                                    8,
                                    32,
                                    4*width,colorSpaceRef,
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    provider,NULL,NO,renderingIntent);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    return newImage;
}

- (NSArray *)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count{
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

// First get the image into your data buffer
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);

// Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
for (int ii = 0 ; ii < count ; ++ii)
{
    CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    byteIndex += 4;

    UIColor *acolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
    [result addObject:acolor];
}

free(rawData);

return result;
}

-(UIColor *)colorOfArmy:(NSString *)army{
UIColor *color;
army = [army stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\a" withString:@""];
if([army isEqual:@"france"]){
    color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.3137254 green:0.3686274 blue:0.9058823 alpha:1];
}
if([army isEqual:@"germany"]){
    color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.6352941 green:0.4313725 blue:0.3372549 alpha:1];
}
if([army isEqual:@"uk"]){
    color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.8941176 green:0.4235294 blue:0.4941176 alpha:1];
}
if([army isEqual:@"italy"]){
    color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.5137254 green:0.1215686 blue:0.4745098 alpha:1];
}
if([army isEqual:@"ussr"]){
    color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.3607843 green:0.0823529 blue:0.1215686 alpha:1];
}
if([army isEqual:@"japan"]){
    color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.9215686 green:0.6156862 blue:0.3137254 alpha:1];
}
if([army isEqual:@""]){
    color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.1215686 green:0.2823529 blue:0.1607843 alpha:1];
}
if(color == nil){
    NSLog(@"the problem was %@", army);
}
return color;
}

-(UIImage *)imageOfTerritoryWithNewArmy:(NSString *)army AndOldTerritoryImage:(UIImage *)oldImg{
CGImageRef image = oldImg.CGImage;
NSInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
NSInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
NSArray *rgba = [self getRGBAsFromImage:oldImg atX:0 andY:0 count:width * height];
NSMutableArray *fixedRGBA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIColor *armyColor = [self colorOfArmy:army];
for(UIColor *pixel in rgba){
    CGFloat red;
    CGFloat green;
    CGFloat blue;
    CGFloat alpha;
    if ([pixel respondsToSelector:@selector(getRed:green:blue:alpha:)]) {
        [pixel getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    } else {
        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(pixel.CGColor);
        red = components[0];
        green = components[1];
        blue = components[2];
        alpha = components[3];
    }
    red = red * 255;
    green = green * 255;
    blue = blue * 255;
    if(alpha > 0){
        if(red < 50 && green < 50 && blue < 50){
            [fixedRGBA addObject:pixel];
        }
        else{
            [fixedRGBA addObject:armyColor];
        }
    }
    else{
        [fixedRGBA addObject:pixel];
    }
}
return [self createImageWithRGB:fixedRGBA width:width height:height];
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when the image is drawn again, all of the pixels that used to be blank because they have an alpha value of 0 are displayed as white. How can I get these pixels to still be displayed as clear pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the image, you should specify that it contains an alpha channel. That is, instead of:

```
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
```

use:

```
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast;
```

See [the CGImage interface specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your else clause here is where you want to set the color to clear

```
    if(alpha > 0){
        rawData[4*i] = red * 255;
        rawData[4*i+1] = green * 255;
        rawData[4*i+2] = blue * 255;
        rawData[4*i+3] = alpha * 255;
    }
    else{
        rawData[4*i] = 255;
        rawData[4*i+1] = 255;
        rawData[4*i+2] = 255;
        rawData[4*i+3] = 255;
    }
```

You have to change the last assignment to 0

```
    if(alpha > 0){
        rawData[4*i] = red * 255;
        rawData[4*i+1] = green * 255;
        rawData[4*i+2] = blue * 255;
        rawData[4*i+3] = alpha * 255;
    }
    else{
        rawData[4*i] = 255;
        rawData[4*i+1] = 255;
        rawData[4*i+2] = 255;
        rawData[4*i+3] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: I just changed that but still the images have white in the areas they should be clear